# Why does my Laptop overheat ever so often and shut down with Ubuntu 11.10 installed?

Tags: shutdown, overheating

I had Windows 7 until yesterday, and then i wiped out my hard disc to install Ubuntu 11.10. But I've noticed that it overheats VERY quickly and gives you no reaction time and just switches off! similar to what would happen if you were to remove battery and unplug the power source! I had a similar problem when I was running the laptop on Windows 7 but that happened rarely. I have an HP Pavilion g6 which is less than a year old now. I want to know if theres any settings I can change or do anything that'll help me overcome this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to clean the fan.

Answer (score 2):

can you list your notebook specs? generally, it can be a problem with graphics hardware, cooling system(fan), or bios. check hp website whether your model has any available bios updates. one major reason of overheating, normally overlooked, is cleaning of notebook's cooling system. i faced same problem last year.

Comment: I second cleaning the cooling system and fans, many a time I've had similar problems, and cleaning out the dust and fur resolved the issue.  Grab a can of air, or an air compressor (be careful, they are powerful and can unseat components) and have at 'er.

Comment: Specs : intel i5 processor, 4 GB RAM + 1 GB graphics card, 500GB hard disc. Anything I've missed out on?

Comment: you hardware specs are pretty recent. 'intel gen. 2 core i' doesn't have heating issues because of switchable graphics. i reckon cleaning cpu fan and heat sinks. i suppose your notebook is still in warranty, so it's better to get some FREE after sale services. second, if there's a bios update available from your vendor, go for it.